# Mpdf Remove space between header and body content

Tags: php, mpdf

I have tried to remove the white space between the header(Dynamic) and body(Dynamic) but can't get it to work. kindly find the following image

[image]

Space is increasing with header content, kindly find the following image
[image]

I am using following code for mpdf

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';  
if ($header != '') {
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<p class="text-center" style="margin:0px;padding: 0px!important">' . $header . '</p>', '', true);
}
if ($footer != '') {
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<p class="text-center" style="margin:0px!important">' . $footer . '</p>', '', true);
}
```

**stretch** used for display header and footer on every page

Comment: Did you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing with this config:

```
$config = array(
            'format' => 'A4',
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'margin_header' => 20,
            'margin_footer' => 10,
            'orientation' => 'P'
        );
$mpdf = new Mpdf($config);
```

Comment: margin_header => 20 add more space from top of page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this configuration:

```
$config = array(
    'format' => 'A4',
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'orientation' => 'P'
    'margin_top' => -30,
    'margin_header' => 2,
    'setAutoTopMargin' => 'pad',
);
```